# LimeTextExplainer for MultiClass classification - Facing issue for explain instance with custom classifier function

Tags: lime

```
exp = explainer.explain_instance(df_val_final.Description[idx],predproba_list,num_features=5, top_labels=2)
```

While executing the explain instance of LimeTextExplainer, the above statement keeps on executing continuously with the below warning message. Execution stops only if I interrupt the kernel

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\torch_core.py:83: UserWarning: Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input
  warn('Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\torch_core.py:83: UserWarning: Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input
 warn('Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\torch_core.py:83: UserWarning: Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input
  warn('Tensor is int32: upgrading to int64; for better performance use int64 input')
```

I want to use my own custom classifier model and hence I wrote a classifier function - predproba_list, which returns a numpy array of predicted probabilities for the classes
Below is the function code

```
def predproba_list(test1) :
    pred = learn_clf.predict(test1)
    return np.array(pred[2])
```

pred[2] vaue is tensor([0.1423, 0.2133, 0.6444]) which i then convert to a numpy array

Can you please advise if the return value of the function is as expected by the explain instance's classifier function, and what could be causing the code to keep on executing without any result?

Comment: Now I am getting the below error :
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5000, 1].

5000 is the default value for argument num_samples in function explain_instance() if it is not explicitly defined.
How is the value for num_samples determined if need to set it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with the **LimeTextExplainer** and stumbled over your question. The return value of your `predproba_list` should be an array of arrays of floats. e.g.:

```
predproba_list('a') 

return:
array([[0.07965168, 0.07578776, 0.2927914 , 0.06609259, 0.03115178]])
```

I hope this helps.